# Можно ли перехватить операцию вставить в Excel 2010?

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, vsto

Здравствуйте.

Есть сценарий. Пользователь копирует текстовые данные в определённом формате и хочет их вставить в таблицу Excel 2010.

Требуется в Add-In перехватить эти данные, распарсить и вставить их в ячейки с требуемым оформлением.

Возможно ли такое сделать на C# при помощи VSTO?

Пытаюсь через элемент `command` в `RibbonUI`, но никак не могу подобрать нужный idMso:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" loadImage="GetImage" onLoad="OnLoadRibonUI" >
  <commands>
    <command idMso="PasteTextOnly" onAction="OnAction" />
  </commands>
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть событие `SheetChange`, которое срабатывает после каких-либо изменений на листе.
Вот таким способом можно понять, что произошла вставка.

```
private void Application_SheetChange(object Sh, Excel.Range Target)
{
    var t = this.Application.CommandBars["Standard"].Controls["&Undo"];
    if (t.TooltipText == "&Undo Paste (Ctrl+Z)")
    {

    }
}
```

По идее, дальше можно сделать форматирование, вызвать Undo и заменить своим форматированием.

Не знаю, может быть более красивый способ, что бы предотвратить вообще ненужную вставку и вставить сразу отформатировванный текст.

---

Нашел решение через [WinApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120199/how-to-get-the-keypress-event-from-a-word-2010-addin-developed-in-c).

Заключается в перехвате сочетаний клавиш.

Если ты поймал CTRL+V, тогда его глушишь, а сам забираешь информацию из буфера обмена.

Comment: А как на счёт локализации Excel? В русском, немецком и т.д. также работает?

Comment: На счет локализации нет возможности проверить, так как стоят английский офис. Однако, доступ к контролам можно получить по индексам. Есть еще второй вариант, который заключается в перхвате кнопок пользователя.